# Error C2562 when using (and exporting) boost::shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, dll

Hi fellow programmers,

I'm creating a C++ DLL library in which I'm using boost's (1.55) shared_ptr.
Howewer, when I'm compiling the project with Visual Studio 2013 a bunch of wild errors C2562 appears:

```
Error   1   error C2562: 'boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::i18n::ITranslationSource>::operator []' : 'void' function returning a value    f:\developer\cplus\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp  663 1   MEngine
Error   2   error C2562: 'boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::i18n::ITranslationSource>::operator []' : 'void' function returning a value    f:\developer\cplus\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp  663 1   MEngine
Error   3   error C2562: 'boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::Object::GameObject>::operator []' : 'void' function returning a value  f:\developer\cplus\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp  663 1   MEngine
Error   4   error C2562: 'boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::Object::GameObject>::operator []' : 'void' function returning a value  f:\developer\cplus\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp  663 1   MEngine
Error   5   error C2562: 'boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::Object::GameObject>::operator []' : 'void' function returning a value  f:\developer\cplus\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp  663 1   MEngine
Error   6   error C2562: 'boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::i18n::ITranslationSource>::operator []' : 'void' function returning a value    f:\developer\cplus\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp  663 1   MEngine
Error   7   error C2562: 'boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::i18n::ITranslationSource>::operator []' : 'void' function returning a value    f:\developer\cplus\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp  663 1   MEngine
Error   8   error C2562: 'boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::i18n::ITranslationSource>::operator []' : 'void' function returning a value    f:\developer\cplus\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp  663 1   MEngine
```

As you can see there's the same error for every shared_ptr template instantiation.
The thing is I never use that operator, so shouldn't the code for it not be generated?

In that case it is and it is completely understandable why that error appears, because in the shared_ptr.h there is this:

```
typename boost::detail::sp_array_access< T >::type operator[] ( std::ptrdiff_t i ) const
{
    BOOST_ASSERT( px != 0 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( i >= 0 && ( i < boost::detail::sp_extent< T >::value || boost::detail::sp_extent< T >::value == 0 ) );

    return px[ i ];
}
```

and that:

```
template< class T > struct sp_array_access
{
    typedef void type;
};
...
template< class T > struct sp_array_access< T[] >
{
    typedef T & type;
};
...
```

Which means that for smart_ptr< T > if T is not an array the return type of operator[] is void, so the code for the operator will not compile.

So the real problem is (I think) that the code for the operator is generated but it shouldn't.
I need to export the shared_ptr to my DLL's interface and since it's a template I'm using this to instantiate and export it:

```
EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class MENGINE_API boost::shared_ptr<MEngine::i18n::ITranslationSource>;
```

where the macros are (pretty standard):

```
#ifdef MENGINE_EXPORTS
#define MENGINE_API _declspec(dllexport)
#define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE
#else
#define MENGINE_API _declspec(dllimport)
#define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE extern
#endif
```

Does the export statement which I'm using causes the generation of everything in the template?
If this is true then how can I get past that and achieve the export?

Apologies for my English :)
Correcting me is also much appreciated as I'm willing to learn :)

Comment: Template classes should never be part of public Dll interface.

Comment: I acknowledge the consequences and the library is meant to be used in environments where there is complete control over the toolchain and versions of included headers and linked libraries.

I'm actually releasing the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 14.7.2 [temp.explicit] para 8:

> An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the
>   same kind (declaration or definition) of each of its members (not including members inherited from base
>   classes) that has not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation unit containing the explicit
>   instantiation, except as described below.

Without espousing all the detail "described below", your explicit instantiation instantiates all members well-defined or otherwise. This is the point of explicit instantiation: to have all the code for every member defined in one place. At the point of instantation, it's not clear which if any members will actually be used: for all you know, some client that links to your library may use that `operator[]`.

The ideal fix is (wild speculation here) to use `std::enable_if` to remove the `operator[]` overloads for non-array types instead of making the code ill-formed for non-array types.

Some other options:

- Don't explicitly instantiate anything.
- Explicitly instantiate each of the desired members individually, avoiding the ill-formed members.

Comment: By design of boost's shared_ptr users cannot use operator[] if T is not an array type (it would cause the generation of operators code and result in C2562 as in my case) and it is not in any of my explecit instantiations. I'm not very familiar with enable_if but doesn't using it mean I need to modify boost's code (rather not possible)?

Comment: @MichaelK.Sondej The problem is that the design doesn't make it so that the improper operators are unusable, it makes them ill-formed. Explicit instantiation of the template specialization forces instantiation of all members - even the ill-formed ones - taking it off the table as a usable solution. A couple of your other choices are to explicitly instantiate member-by-member instead of the whole class at one go, or to simply avoid explicit instantiation altogether.

Comment: But how to avoid it? Is it possible to export a templated object to a dll interface without explicit instantiation? Encapsulation in a non-template class doesn't really make any sense and on the other hand encapsulation in my own template class would simply not work I think (implementation is in the header, so the boost::shared_ptr would also need to be exported?).

Comment: @MichaelK.Sondej [Here's an example of what I mean by instantiating individual members instead of entire template classes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8a212cb77f0ba61). That said, if you are "leaking" `boost::shared_ptr` out to clients of your DLL you are already critically relying on the client using the identical header implementation of `shared_ptr`. I don't think you gain anything by exporting `shared_ptr<YourClass>` from the DLL instead of simply exporting `YourClass` and letting the client instantiate `shared_ptr<YourClass>` themselves from the header.

Comment: I didn't know it would work, seems I must read much more about DLLs. Thank you!